# As soon as the input field is valid, the other element gets focuses

Tags: jquery, html, parsley.js

I've recently started using Parsley and I have encountered a problem.
Basically I have a three-input form that needs to be validated, and until everything is correct next button is disabled.

The problem is this:

If I use on blur, event as soon as I'm done typing on the first input, the second become focused and I can't do anything until I fill that input correctly. I can't even edit the first input field until all the others are filled.

On using the keyup event or the combination of the two, as soon as I type the first letter in the first field, it moves me to the second input box.

Can you help me with my code?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#signup-form1").parsley();
      $('input').on('keyup blur', function() {
        $("#signup-form1").parsley().validate();
        if ($("#signup-form1").parsley().isValid()) {
          $('#submit1').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
          $('#submit1').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
      });
```

```html
<form id="signup-form1" action="#" data-parsley-validate novalidate>
  <input id="first-name" class="form-control" type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name" parsley-trigger="change" required>
  <input id="last-name" class="form-control" type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last name" parsley-trigger="change" required>
  <input id="email" class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" parsley-type="email" parsley-trigger="change" required>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" id="submit1" disabled="disabled">Next</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is:

1) trigger validation sooner than standard, i.e. with `data-featherlight-trigger="input"`

2) toggle the state of your button by listening to the `form:success` and `form:error` events.

HTH